# How to fix an invalid multibyte string error with recommenderRegistry$get_entries()?

Tags: r, recommenderlab

I'm trying "recommenderlab" package and getting an error with recommenderRegistry$get_entries() fuction.

To get the info about recommendation algorithms, I tried

```
library(recommenderlab)  
recommenderRegistry$get_entries()
```

But the output is truncated in the middle as below.

```
$AR_binaryRatingMatrix
Recommender method: AR for binaryRatingMatrix
Description: Recommender based on association rules.
Reference: NA
Parameters:
Error in dput(p, control = list()) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe><63><6f>nfidence<ff><fe>"
```

When I tried

```
names(recommenderRegistry[["AR", "binaryRatingMatrix"]][['parameters']])
```

all the parameters are displayed without an error.

```
[1] "support"         "confidence"      "maxlen"          "sort_measure"    "sort_decreasing" "apriori_control" "verbose"
```

Additionally, I tried re-installing it, but the result is the same.
recommenderRegistry$get_entries() should show 15 algorithms available in this pacakge. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

The system information is like below
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default
locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949 [2] LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949 [3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C [5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949
attached base packages: [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1 [3] yaml_2.2.0

Comment: A working example might help.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik   
`library(recommenderlab)`  
`recommenderRegistry$get_entries()`

Comment: Just installed the package from CRAN and ran the code you suggested. I get no errors and a lot of output.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, it should show you 15 recommender models with their details, but in my case, the output is truncated in the middle. Re-installing didn't resolve this issue.

Comment: You should probably include more information about your system, perhaps?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, you are right.   
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                
[5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1   
[3] yaml_2.2.0

Comment: Please use the edit button to add extra information. Comments aren't really designed to handle these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem may be your locale setting:

`locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949 [2] LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949 [3] LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C [5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949`

You can try `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")`

Comment: Sorry for the late update. The issue was cleared when I tried replicating it in my latest environment with R 4.2.0 and RStudio 2022.02.3.